# What was Max Pomeranc's role in Definitely, Maybe, and in which scene was he?

Tags: casting, definitely-maybe

[Max Pomeranc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Pomeranc), known for his role as [Josh Waitzkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Waitzkin) in [Searching for Bobby Fischer/The Innocent Moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Searching_for_Bobby_Fischer), was apparently in [Definitely, Maybe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitely,_Maybe).

Who was he? In which scene was he?

Comment: Google Images says it's [here](http://91.207.61.14/m/uploads/v_p_images/2008/01/6012_10_screenshot.png), if that helps. (He was also a [crew member](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0690051/).)

Comment: @Walt Mr white, is he the one in red?

Comment: [It seems so](http://www.teenidols4you.com/blink/Actors/max_pomeranc/mpo-bobby_fischer_133.jpg). See them side by side.

Comment: @Walt ummmmm, am I supposed to compare them from different ages? I can't recognise how Saul Berenson and Inigo Montoya have the same actor. Maybe it's just me...

Comment: Same exact expression in those 2 pics, IMHO.

Comment: @Walt IYHO, does either picture resemble his recent photos on his twitter or LinkedIn accounts?

Comment: I dunno, haven't been there. (Are you sure they're official, BTW?)

Comment: @Walt Well they look like him :P